# How to prove $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ converges only for $p>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

Prove $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ converges only for $p>1$.

For this I need to prove that for $p>1$ and some $n>N\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\frac1{n^p}\le\frac1{p^n}$$

Then I can show that geometric series on RHS is an upper bound. But I am not able to prove this step.

Edit: Above inequality doesn't work as pointed out in the comments. Is there a way to bound this series by some geometric series.

Comment: It's not true. You cannot prove the convergence this way. Try the integral test, or else Cauchy condensation.

Comment: [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) essentially says that $\sum 1/n^p$ converges if and only if the geometric series with base $2^{1-p}$ converges, i.e. if and only if $p>1$.

Comment: I am following the book understanding analysis by abott and this is given as an exercise. And the question asked to use geometric series to prove this. Cauchy condensation test and the integral test have still not been discussed so I want to avoid using them. This is problem 2.7.7

Comment: The inequality you mentioned will not work. It does not even work for $p=2.$

Comment: I see that now. Do you have any idea on how to bound this series using geometric series

Comment: Follow @AlexanderBurstein's advice. See if you can show that $\frac{1}{n^p}<\frac{1}{2^{(p-1)n}}$ for $p>1$.

Comment: got it thanks, although this uses the cauchy condensation test is there another way?

Comment: Actually, I think my suggested inequality is wrong. That would not be the geometric series to consider. So I am stumped.

Comment: Yeah the inequality doesn't work but the condensation test does.